# Prolog, strange answer of setof

Tags: prolog

I'm using the online compiler https://swish.swi-prolog.org/

Given the next facts:

```
frontier(spain,france).
frontier(spain,portugal).
frontier(portugal,spain).
frontier(france,spain).
frontier(france,italy).
frontier(france,germany).
frontier(france,belgium).
frontier(france,swiztland).
frontier(belgium,netherlands).
frontier(belgium,france).
frontier(belgium,germany).
frontier(netherlands,germany).
frontier(netherlands,belgium).
frontier(germany,netherlands).
frontier(germany,belgium).
frontier(germany,france).
frontier(germany,austria).
frontier(germany,swiztland).
frontier(austria,germany).
frontier(austria,swiztland).
frontier(austria,italy).
frontier(swiztland,austria).
frontier(swiztland,france).
frontier(swiztland,germany).
frontier(swiztland,italy).
frontier(italy,france).
frontier(italy,swiztland).
frontier(italy,austria).
```

I would like to obtain all of the countries but without obtain repeated ones.

Thus, I use a setof predicate, which avoids the repeated, like this:

```
 setof(Country, (frontier(Country,_)), Countries).
```

The problem is that, when I executed the query, I obtained some iterations:

> 1. [germany, italy, swiztland]
> 2. [france, germany, netherlands]
> 3. [belgium, germany, italy, spain, swiztland],
> 4. [austria, belgium, france, netherlands, swiztland]
> 5. [austria, france, swiztland]
> 6. [belgium, germany]
> 7. [spain]
> 8. [france, portugal]
> 9. [austria, france, germany, italy]

I don't understand why, I was expected that the list `Countries` return me the list of all the countries without repeated ones and sorted, that's why I use the anonymus variable in the second argument of the predicate frontier, because I don't care about the second argument, only I want the first argument without repeated ones.

Any help?

Comment: It's because of the `_` argument. You need to use a universal quantifier. You'll find the description in documentation. You want: `setof(Country, X^frontier(Country,X), Countries).`

Comment: That makes sense, I completely forget about that, thank you